# Spring-boot kafka app to GraalVM native image - org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.DefaultKafkaClientSupplier could not be found

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, graalvm

I have Java Spring-boot application using spring-kafka and kafka-streams.
I'm trying to build GraalVM native image with

```
 mvn -Pnative spring-boot:build-image
```

The build is successful but when I try to run the image in docker I get exception:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.DefaultKafkaClientSupplier for configuration default.client.supplier: Class org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.DefaultKafkaClientSupplier could not be found.
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parseType(ConfigDef.java:747)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef$ConfigKey.<init>(ConfigDef.java:1175)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.define(ConfigDef.java:155)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.define(ConfigDef.java:175)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.define(ConfigDef.java:214)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.define(ConfigDef.java:376)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.define(ConfigDef.java:389)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig.<clinit>(StreamsConfig.java:1008)
        ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Kafka config:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    producer:
      value-serializer: "org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer"
      properties:
        spring:
          json:
            type:
              mapping: "ErrorReportDomain:com.kt.kafka.messagingprocessor.domain.ErrorReportDomain"
    client-id: messaging-processor
    bootstrap-servers:
      - "XXX"
    security:
      protocol: SASL_PLAINTEXT
    properties:
      sasl:
        mechanism: SCRAM-SHA-512
        jaas:
          config: org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username="XXX" password="XXX";
    streams:
      application.id: messaging-processor
      properties:
        spring:
          json:
            trusted:
              packages: '*'
        default:
          key:
            serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
          value:
            serde: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerde
```

Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We recently added Kafka Streams hints into GraalVM Reachability Metadata: https://github.com/oracle/graalvm-reachability-metadata/pull/422.

But apparently that has not been released yet.

So, to make it working in your app, you need to provide those hints manually.

It looks like you don't use Spring Cloud Stream, so I suggest to copy/paste this class into your project: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/main/binders/kafka-binder/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/kafka/streams/aot/KafkaStreamsBinderRuntimeHints.java

Probably with some modification removing Spring Cloud Stream specific entries.

See more docs about manual hints registration: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/aot.html#aot.hints

Comment: Thanks a lot. After adding some other hints it finally works.